# How do I keep my bootstrap nav bar from collapsing (I want it to show a hamburger) on mobile devices? My first CSS project

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

How do I keep my bootstrap nav bar from collapsing (I want it to show a hamburger) on mobile devices? Sorry if this is a silly question this is my first CSS project.

This is my nav bar using bootstrap classes...

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg "> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#menu">Menu</a>
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Our Story</a>
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="https://www.indeed.com/">Careers</a>
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#contact">Contact</a>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Read the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is working as expected. The only problem is the hamburger is transparent without `.navbar-light` or `.navbar-dark`. The simplest solution is to add `.navbar-light` to your `.navbar`, this will make the hamburger black and therefore visible. You could alternatively, use `.navbar-dark` and apply a dark background color `.bg-dark` to get a white hamburger.

Also, note that your use of `.navbar-expand-lg` means the hamburger will show over the collapsed menu on all screens smaller than the `lg` breakpoint.
Here is the relevant excerpt from the docs concerning responsive behaviors:

> ... `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl}` classes ... determine when their content collapses behind a button
> ...
> For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand class.
>
> -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

In the working snippet below I have only added the class `.navbar-light` to your code.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#menu">Menu</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="https://www.indeed.com/">Careers</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#contact">Contact</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```